# Aproximation of a picewise smooth function

Tags: real-analysis, hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces, convolution, fractional-sobolev-spaces

I am working in a Hilbert space which is the closure of $C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ with respect to the inner product given by
\begin{equation}
\tau(f,g)=\Re{\int_{0}^{\infty}p \hat{f}(-p)\hat{g}(p)}dp,
\end{equation}
where $\hat{f}$ denotes the Fourier transform of $f$. Call $K$ this Hilbert space.

I have a function $g(x)=\theta(t-x)h(x)$ where $\theta$ the Heaviside step function and $h\in C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $h(t)=0$, then $g$ is picewise smooth function with compact support, but ¿How can I prove that $g\in K$?
I tried to approximate $g$ by convolution with standerd mollifiers, but it didn't work to me.

Moreover I am interesting in know if any picewise smooth function with compact support is in $K$.

Comment: In PDEs, that space is often known as a "homogeneous Sobolev space" and it is denoted by $\dot H^{1/2}(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @GiuseppeNegro, but I am not absolutly sure of that because $\tau$ can be written in the form  $\tau(f,g)=-\frac{1}{\pi}PV\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}dx\,dy\frac{f(x)g(y)}{(x-y)^2}$ instead of $PV\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}dx\,dy\frac{|f(x)-g(y)|^2}{(x-y)^2}$ as the seminorms in this homogeneous Sobolev space.

Comment: Hey @GabrielPalau: so I frankly don't know what to add, but there is a nice little paper called "Hitchhiker's guide to fractional Sobolev spaces" which could contain interesting information for you.